# Equation of a hyperbola given its asymptotes

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the equation of the hyperbola whose asymptotes are $3x-4y+7$ and $4x+3y+1=0$ and which pass through the origin.

The equation of the hyperbola is obtained in my reference as
$$
(3x-4y+7)(4x+3y+1)=K=7
$$

So it make use of the statement, the equation of the hyperbola = equation of pair of asymptotes + constant

I understand that the pair of straight lines is the limiting case of hyperbola.

Why does the equation to the hyperbola differ from the equation of pair of asymptotes only by a constant ?

Comment: Fun fact about hyperbolas: *The the product of the (signed) distances from a point to the asymptotes is constant.* ... (Also note: "hyperbolic geometry" is [quite a different subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry), so don't use that tag to indicate the conic section.)

Comment: @Blue could you pls comment on how to find the equation of the hyperbola from the given asymptotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{4x+3y+1}{5}=\pm\frac{3x-4y+7}{5}\\
\implies x+7y-6=0\;;\; 7x-y+8=0\text{ which are the axis of the hyperbola with centre }(-1,1)\\
$$
Since $m_1m_2=-1\implies$ asymptotes are perpendicular $\implies$ rectangular hyperbola

$$
\frac{(x+7y-6)^2}{50a^2}-\frac{(7x-y+8)^2}{50a^2}=\pm1\\
\text{At }(0,0): \frac{18}{25a^2}-\frac{32}{25a^2}=\pm1\implies18a^2-32a^2=\pm25a^4\\
-14a^2=\pm25a^4\implies-14a^2=25a^4\text{ not possible}\\
-14a^2=-25a^4\implies \boxed{a^2=\frac{14}{25}}\\
\frac{(x+7y-6)^2}{50a^2}-\frac{(7x-y+8)^2}{50a^2}=-1\\
\frac{(7x-y+8)^2}{50a^2}-\frac{(x+7y-6)^2}{50a^2}=1\\
(7x-y+8)^2-(x+7y-6)^2=50a^2=50.\frac{14}{25}=28\\
x^2(48)+y^2(-48)+xy(-28)+x(124)+y(68)+28=28\\
\color{blue}{12x^2-7xy-12y^2+31x+17y=0}
$$

Comment: +1. (Feel free to accept your own answer.) ... Incidentally, you can tighten your presentation a bit, since you unnecessarily duplicated effort in your cases. For instance, you could put a "$\pm 1$" on the right side of your proposed hyperbola equation, which accommodates the fact that you aren't sure which order the terms on the left should be in. (Can you see why?) Then, upon substituting $(x,y)=(0,0)$, you find $-14a^2=\pm 25 a^4$. This settles the sign ambiguity ("$\pm$" must be "$-$") while simultaneously giving you the needed value of $a^2$. Then proceed with the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the consistent help, and I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation of a hyperbola  $$ \frac {(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} -\frac {(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1 \tag {1}$$

Which has its asymptotes $$(y-y_0)=\pm \frac {b}{a}(x-x_0)$$

Upon multioplication of the equations of the two asymptotes we get $$(y-y_0)^2 = \frac {b^2}{a^2} (x-x_0)^2$$ 
or  $$\frac {(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} -\frac {(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} =0 \tag {2}$$

As you see the difference of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is a constant.

Comment: Thanks. but this I can see for the general case. But my doubt is why that is the case, is there any justification for that ?. And is there a simpler way to solve this given in this case the hyperbola is rotated thats why the $xy$ term in the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a comment:

> For a point on a hyperbola, the product of the *signed* distances (say, $d_1$ and $d_2$) to the asymptotes is a constant.
>   $$d_1 d_2 = k \tag{1}$$

(If $k=0$, then the hyperbola degenerates to just the asymptotes themselves.)

Since the signed distances from $(x,y)$ to line $ax+by+c=0$ is 
$$d = \frac{a x + b y + c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \tag{2}$$
it follows that points on the hyperbola with asymptotes $ax+by+c=0$ and $dx+ey+f=0$ satisfy

$$\frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cdot\frac{dx+ey+f}{\sqrt{d^2+e^2}}=k \tag{3}$$

Clearing fractions, and "absorbing" the square roots into the arbitrary constant $k$, we have
$$(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)=k \tag{4}$$

If we know a particular point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the curve, we can substitute to find $k$, whereupon we get the final equation

> $$(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)=(ax_0+by_0+c)(dx_0+ey_0+f) \tag{5}$$

For the specific problem at hand, we have

$$(3x-4y+7)(4x+3y+1)=7\cdot 1 \tag{5}$$

which the reader can expand and reduce.

Comment: How is the product of signed distances to the asymptotes a constant ?

Comment: @ss1729: Well, it's a "known" property; see [item (2) here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Asymptotes). (My use of "signed distance" allows the statement to be translated to my equation (3).) Verifying it for an origin-centered hyperbola with transverse and conjugate semi-axes $p$ and $q$ (and thus asymptotes $q x\pm p y=0$ is straightforward: With this information, the left-hand side of my equation (4) becomes $$(q x+p y)(q x-py)=q^2x^2-p^2y^2=p^2q^2\left(\frac{x^2}{p^2}-\frac{y^2}{q^2}\right)$$We know the large factor reduces to $1$, so the product is a constant, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks. And what if I try to approach the problem as follows: $$
\frac{4x+3y+1}{5}=\pm\frac{3x-4y+7}{5}\\
\implies x+7y-6=0\quad;\quad 7x-y+8=0\text{ which are the axis of the hyperbola with centre }(-1,1)\\
\frac{(4x+3y+1)^2}{25a^2}-\frac{(3x-4y+7)^2}{25b^2}=1
$$

Comment: @ss1729: You've found the axes correctly. However, you should be using *them* in the resulting hyperbola equation, since the difference-of-squares form of the equation uses distances from *the axes*, not the asymptotes; so, you should have $$\frac{(x+7y-6)^2}{50a^2}-\frac{(7x-y+8)^2}{50b^2}=1$$ (Although it's not really obvious which term should be positive.) In any case, you're still left with finding $a^2$ and $b^2$. Substituting $(x,y)=(0,0)$ gives you one condition. Can you tell what the other is?

Comment: Ohh sorry that was a typo.
$$
\frac{(x+7y-6)^2}{50a^2}-\frac{(7x-y+8)^2}{50b^2}=1\implies \frac{18}{25a^2}-\frac{32}{25b^2}=1\implies 18b^2-32a^2=25a^2b^2
$$
I am stuck here with two unknown coeff with one equation. I don't know if I can make use of the fact that the centre of the hyperbola is (-1,1).

Comment: @ss1729: Hint: There's actually only one unknown. (The nature of the asymptotes makes the hyperbola special.)

Comment: asymptotes are perpendicular, i think that makes it a rectangular hyperbola ?

Comment: because $\frac{-b^2}{a^2}=-1\implies a=b$

Comment: @ss1729: Indeed! So, $a=b$, and you should be able to take it from there. (Compare what you get to my answer.) ... Since we're now getting an "extended discussion" warning, I'm going to stop commenting. Good work and good luck!